# Ubuntu 16.04.3 Live USB Doesn't like my Nvidia Gtx 1070 - Getting weird stripes/dot-matrix looking text

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, usb, display

I'm trying to boot an Ubuntu live ISO from a multiboot flash drive (and as such, the menu is more of the typical basic grub thing instead of ubuntu's fancy thing). The non-ubuntu based linux distros on it work perfectly on this machine, but all ubuntu-based ones (Xubuntu, Mint, Elementary) don't, with the odd exception of KDE Neon. I'm getting these weird green and purple stripes appearing first, followed by that text, and then the text will go away. I've tried switching to TTYs, but the text is so big and positioned weird, so it runs right off the screen and is basically useless. Here's what the screen looks like:

[image: The screen it gives me, with green and purple stripes and dot-matrix appearing text]

I've tried this USB on my laptop, which has a different graphics card and it works perfectly. I've verified it with checksums and everything. I also tried disabling the nouveau module (might have done it wrong), and I've tried nomodset (once again, may have done it wrong but I tried it a couple different ways). The display is 1680x1050 (I also have a second Full HD monitor attached too), so the text should be WAY smaller than this.

[image: Basic grub2 options]

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error running a GTX 970 and an i5-7600k. I'm not sure why, but for some reason the Nouveau drivers aren't happy with my new hardware even though the GTX 970 always worked fine in the past for Live CDs on my old system. Maybe the new CPU has something to do with it? My old install boots fine because it already has proprietary NVIDIA drivers on it, but the live USB gets a very similar screen to what you're seeing.

**The fix:**
Switch to your integrated graphics as the primary GPU and boot on there. Be sure to unplug all monitors from your GPU. For some reason, even though I set integrated graphics as my primary GPU using a secondary monitor, the the Nouveau drivers still detected my first monitor and caused the boot to fail.

If you plan to make a fresh install, be sure to boot it and install the NVIDIA drivers before switching back to your NVIDIA card.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have integrated graphics on my desktop system.